# Деление двух длинных чисел

Tags: c++, числа

Изначально было необходимо написать функцию, которая производит целочисленное деление двух длинных чисел аналогично бинарному поиску. Сами числа хранятся в массивах: одна ячейка - одна цифра. Если я все правильно понял, для этого нужно уметь делить число пополам. Как это можно это реализовать (деление на 2)?

Comment: @inf926t, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[@inf926t](/users/26454/inf926t), м.б.

```
    char value[n]; // Ваше число
    ...
    int l = n / 2; // его середина
```

это?

Comment: я так понимаю, это вброс?

Comment: Это я так пошутил в комментарии, а кто-то (видимо из модераторов) преобразовал в ответ.